# What are these chips on my Quadro K4200

Tags: cooling, nvidia-quadro

I was re-applying thermal paste because I noticed it idling high (I bought it used) at 70-80 °C.

I removed the HS and noticed these chips where the surrounding plastic seems blemished from heat.

I've decided to add a 1/2 mm thick thermal pad to supplement its thermal connection to the HS.

What are these chips exactly, voltage regulators?
[image: K4200 - chips]
I'm talking about the chips R22 and R33.

I should eventually replace the rest of the thermal pads between the PCB and plastic mount, but Ill save it for another day. Ill see how much better the thermals are once my HDMI to DP adapter comes in.

[image: K4200 - chips w/ pads]

Comment: How can we identify ICs if they are covered by thermal pads? Typically, R, on a circuit is an indicator for a Resistor so likely a Resistor pack

Comment: I'm idling at 36'C and maxing at 81'C. The thermal pads didn't hurt. 

I think ramhound is right, its more likely a resistor pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are VRM's - Voltage Regulator Modules. They can get very hot and must be able to disipate the heat energy. Failure to do so will break them. A 0.5mm thermal pad will probably not cut it. I would be looking at a few millimetres at least. I would also question whether you have been sold a pup. There appears to be a few of the VRM's missing which will probably put additional load on the remaining ones leading to much quicker total failure. But then again, looking at a teardown video, they may not...

Comment: I thought it was a VRM initially as well. They undoubtedly generate a lot of heat; the tip of the copper pipe where the VRMs were below was almost green/gray from heat and age. I could stack the thermal pads and get better connection, but what I've done already seems to have helped the thermals. It should work well enough as a server monitor GPU.

Comment: I thought there were some VRMs missing as well, but it sees thats to spec. They look easy to replace if they ever go out, just two solder points. Harder to find the exact part without much info on the piece.